# How to set array elements with Moq?

Tags: c#, moq

I am using Moq to mock a view and model to test a presenter.

I would like to use mocking to confirm that array members of my model and view are indeed set in the ResetStatuses and UpdateTxtStatuses methods.

However, running the test results in an error at my call to ResetStatuses, with the error message:

```
Result StackTrace:  
at DSimGui.SocketStatusIGSSPresenter.ResetStatuses() in C:\dev\dir\DG\DSimGui\SocketStatusIGSSPresenter.cs:line 89
   at DSimGuiTest.SocketStatusIGSSTest.VerifyResetStatuses() in C:\dev\dir\DG\DSimGuiTest\SocketStatusIGSSTest.cs:line 82
Result Message: 
Test method DSimGuiTest.SocketStatusIGSSTest.VerifyResetStatuses threw exception: 
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

I thought that this required me to use SetupSet to prepare the members for setting, but using SetupSet on txtClientStatuses resulted in another error:

```
Result StackTrace:  
at DSimGuiTest.SocketStatusIGSSTest.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<VerifyResetStatuses>b__3(SocketStatusIGSSIModel a) in C:\dev\dir\DG\DSimGuiTest\SocketStatusIGSSTest.cs:line 88
   at Moq.Mock.SetupSetImpl[T,TCall](Mock`1 mock, Action`1 setterExpression, Func`5 callFactory) in C:\projects\moq4\Source\Mock.cs:line 666
   at Moq.Mock.SetupSetPexProtected[T](Mock`1 mock, Action`1 setterExpression, Condition condition) in C:\projects\moq4\Source\Mock.cs:line 626
   at Moq.PexProtector.Invoke[T1,T2,T3,TResult](Func`4 function, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3) in C:\projects\moq4\Source\PexProtector.cs:line 75
   at DSimGuiTest.SocketStatusIGSSTest.VerifyResetStatuses() in C:\dev\dir\DG\DSimGuiTest\SocketStatusIGSSTest.cs:line 88
Result Message: 
Test method DSimGuiTest.SocketStatusIGSSTest.VerifyResetStatuses threw exception: 
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

How do I correctly call SetupSet for array indexes? Assuming that this will allow the presenter to set array elements without error.

My code is listed below:

**Presenter**

```
public class SocketStatusIGSSPresenter
{
    private readonly SocketStatusIGSSIView view;
    private readonly SocketStatusIGSSIModel model;
    private readonly EventHub eventHub;

    public SocketStatusIGSSPresenter(
        SocketStatusIGSSIView view,
        SocketStatusIGSSIModel model)
    {
        this.view = view;
        view.Presenter = this;

        this.model = model;
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        model.txtClientStatuses = new string[4];
        model.txtServerStatuses = new string[4];
        model.txtIGSSCmd = "";
    }

    public void ResetStatuses()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            model.txtClientStatuses[i] = "0";
            model.txtServerStatuses[i] = "0";
        }
        UpdateTxtStatuses();
    }

    public void UpdateTxtStatuses()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            view.txtClientStatuses[i].Text = model.txtClientStatuses[i];
            view.txtServerStatuses[i].Text = model.txtServerStatuses[i];
        }
    }
}
```

**Test Method**

```
[TestMethod]
public void VerifyResetStatuses()
{
    var model = new Mock<SocketStatusIGSSIModel>();
    model.SetupSet(a => a.txtClientStatuses = It.IsAny<string[]>());
    model.SetupSet(a => a.txtServerStatuses = It.IsAny<string[]>());
    model.SetupSet(a => a.txtIGSSCmd = It.IsAny<string>());

    var view = new Mock<SocketStatusIGSSIView>();
    var eventHub = new EventHub();
    var presenter = new SocketStatusIGSSPresenter(view.Object, model.Object, eventHub);

    // Results in error!
    //for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    //{
    //  model.SetupSet(a => a.txtClientStatuses[i] = It.IsAny<string>());
    //}

    // Results in error!
    //presenter.ResetStatuses();

    // This will be used to verify that txtClientStasuses array elements are set
    //model.VerifySet(a => a.txtClientStatuses[It.IsAny<int>()] = It.IsAny<string>(), Times.Exactly(3));
}
```

**Model interface**

```
public interface SocketStatusIGSSIModel
{
    string[] txtClientStatuses { get; set; }

    string[] txtServerStatuses { get; set; }

    string txtIGSSCmd { get; set; }

    string TxtDataValue { get; set; }

    short TxtSrcSeqCnt { get; set; }
}
```

**View interface**

```
public interface SocketStatusIGSSIView
{
    SocketStatusIGSSPresenter Presenter { set; }

    TextBox[] txtClientStatuses { get; set; }

    TextBox[] txtServerStatuses { get; set; }

    string TxtIGSSCmd { get; set; }

    string TxtDataValue { get; set; }

    string TxtSrcSeqCntValue { get; set; }

    void Show();

    void Hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not mock an array. Create an ordinary array in the test. The code will set the entries of that array.

```
var mockTxtClientStatuses = new string[4]; // or maybe new string[] { "foo", "bar", "x", "y", }
model.Setup(x => x.txtClientStatuses).Returns(mockTxtClientStatuses);
// ...
presenter.ResetStatuses();
// verify that mockTxtClientStatuses has correct entries now
```

If you are not happy with that, as an alternative, use an interface (such as `IList<string>`) that `string[]` implements. That is:

```
public interface SocketStatusIGSSIModel
{
  IList<string> txtClientStatuses { get; set; }
// ...
```

Moq is able to mock an interface, including its indexers. Moq cannot mock a concrete array type such as `string[]`.